# how to set seed of RNG in c++?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, random, c++-cli

Can anyone tell me how to generate same values of Random Number in C++?

I know in Matlab that I can do the following:

```
rng(1)
a= randi(10,1,10)
```

The answer would be same. For example

```
5     8     1     4     2     1     2     4     4     6

5     8     1     4     2     1     2     4     4     6

5     8     1     4     2     1     2     4     4     6
```

It will give me the same values at all time unless the seed is reset.

But I don't know how to do this in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Two different initializations with the same seed will generate the
>   same succession of results in subsequent calls to rand.
>
> If seed is set to 1, the generator is reinitialized to its initial
>   value and produces the same values as before any call to rand or
>   [srand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand).

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h> 

int random = rand();
int next = rand();
int next2 = rand();

//another sequence
srand (time(NULL));
int 2random = rand();
int 2next = rand();
int 2next2 = rand();

//will repeat the first sequence
srand (1);
int 3random = rand();
int 3next = rand();
int 3next2 = rand();
```

Comment: and what library i need to use

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the function [**srand**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) which seeds the random number generator? It is frequently used to seed with the current time, but you can use it to seed with a fixed value if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of a `std::random_device`, which provides possibly non-deterministic uniform random numbers, and use it to seed a random number engine of your choosing:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine gen(rd());
```

---

If you want to know how to seed the C library function `rand`, you need to use [`std::srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand). It is commonly seeded with the current time, `std::time(0)`.

Of course, there's no reason you couldn't use `std::random_device` to seed `rand`.